# bounds and least upper boun

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading some notes for my Real Analysis class and I came across this sentence:

"Note that if instead we had been looking at B = {x ∈ R : x ≤ 1} there
is a maximum - namely 1. (A maximum is always a supremum, but the
converse is false)."

why a supremum is not alwas a maximum? also can someone give a counter example to show that every supremum is a maximum?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by a maximum? An upper bound?
Normally in Analysis, we refer to upper bounds and supremum (or least upper bound).

Comment: A maximum need not exist at all.  $A=\{x \in R: x < 1\}$ has $\sup A = 1$ and $\sup A \not \in A$.  But $\max A$ does not exist.  $1\not \in A$ so $\max A \ne 1$ and if $x < 1$ then there is an $r$ so that $x < r < 1$ and $r\in A$ so $x \ne \max A$.  $\max A$ simply does not exist.

Comment: "also can someone give a counter example to show that every supremum is a maximum?" you mean an counter example that shows *not* every supremum is a maximum.  .... Note: All maximums are suprema; and no maximum is *not* a suprema; but it's possible for a supremum to exist while no maximum exists.  In other words..... either a maximum is a supremum or no maximum exists.

Comment: @Fede1  A maximum is usually defined as $w\in A$ so that for all $a\in A$ then $a \le w$.  I.E.  A maximum is an upper bound that is also a member of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Whats the supremum of $[0, 1)$? 
Whats the maximum of $[0, 1)$?

Comment: the supremum is 1 but there is no maximum since it is an open interval

Comment: @Yassire thus the supremum doesnt not guarantee the existence of a maximum. And thus the supremum is not always the same as the maximum

Comment: yes I got what you are saying